# /usr/local/bin/ not found by Automator and Java but exists in Terminal

Tags: macos, automator, bash, java

Automator Shell Script

```
echo $PATH
eval /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
echo $PATH
```

Results:

after the first `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

after the second `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

As ImageMagick is installed in /usr/local/bin it means that it fails unless I mess with the PATH first
anyone know where Automator (Java is the same) gets its path from and how to permanently add the missing paths

Comment: Seperate Lines echo $PATH >> eval /usr/libexec/path_helper -s >>  echo $PATH

Comment: Results >> first echo = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin second echo = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

Comment: I edited your question. Please check my mods

Comment: The answers for Automator and Java will differ as the first is launched through the GUI and the second most cases will be via command line - there are many duplicates of both on this site

Answer (score 2):

Automator uses the path variable hard coded in the kernel.

```
sysctl user.cs_path
user.cs_path = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Actually, this is the path set for a user's launchd and is then inherited by Automator when you launch the application.

```
launchctl getenv PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Use the absolute paths to your executables or modify the PATH in the Run Shell Script.

Comment: Very interesting! +1  A simple `echo $PATH` in a Run Shell Script confirms this and I have had issues in the past and never checked this!  Now I know why I have had to hard code some paths! :)

Comment: You can also add a `PATH= ...` statement, set to what's in the environment,  to the top of the Run Shell Script  and then not have to hard code the path to the executable.  You can add that to your answer if you want.